# Self-join example review in Books Online

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, self-join

[image]
Here in this example it states that performs a *self-join*, but it joins `Sales.SalesPerson` to `Sales.SalesTerritory`. I knew that self join means joining the same table to itself but here aren't `Sales.SalesPerson` and `Sales.SalesTerritory` different tables? So is this considered self join though the tables are different? or is there a mistake?

[source link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177490(v=sql.105))

Comment: Are SalesPerson and SalesTerritory tables or views of the same table?

Comment: It's not mentioned in the example, but I just checked in AdventureWorks database and they are different tables @McNets

Comment: I also think so @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are right in all observations and it is a mistake.

They are two separate tables (not views) and a self-join means a table joined to itself (and even a view or derived table or CTE joined to itself). You might even consider a join between a table and a view derived from that table to be a self-join but it is not the case here either.

I suggest you submit a bug report.

Link: **[list of `AdventureWorks` tables](http://elsasoft.com/samples/sqlserver_adventureworks/SqlServer.SPRING.KATMAI.AdventureWorks/allTables.htm)**.